# Simplifying Maps

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am just getting into the use of maps into my apps and in GPS apps like "Waze" and gaming apps like "Pokemon Go" the Maps are simplified, not showing things that are not important to the use of the app. When I look at the regular MapKit map, it shows everything and is visually displeasing. How do I customize portions (such as streets) of the MapKit map in a similar way that Waze did in the following picture?

[image]

Comment: Waze has their own map; they don't use MapKit at all.

Comment: Oh god, how would I create and integrate my own Map? @SLaks

Comment: Niantic (Pokémon GO) uses the Google Maps API to pull in data, but then generates their own map using the Unity Game Engine.

Comment: It is possible to replace the tiles in MapKit with your own tiles but this requires a lot of work creating and supplying the tiles. There have been WWDC videos on this topic in the past. For your initial game just use MapKit and get the game working; then look into `MKTileOverlay`, `MKAnnotation` and `MKAnnotationView`. There are quite a few MapKit classes you will need to read up on.

Answer (score 2):

You can't customise the MapKit map in such way you're describing. You should find a different provider. You could try and search for "mapping API".